# Any Possible Way to save clicked element in html and retrieve after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is there any Possible Way to save clicked element in html and retrieve after ajax call.

[image]

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/n4m9584b/1/)

in the demo there are some options, on click of that ajax will trigger in current application. but in jsfiddle im not able to call a ajax.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="search-refine-bar">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p id="ajaxRequest">some bla bla bla..</p>
</div>
```

**on click of Paragraph Tag, Iam requesting a ajax call and retrieving the data.
Issue is in my current Application whenever i trigger a ajax call whole "container" is repainting.**

is there any way out. ?

JS :

```
function makeAjaxCallforAttrVal(b, e, d) {
    appendCurtain();
    var g = closeAllOpenModals();
    var f = e;
    $("#terminalNodeDetails").val(f);
    window.location.hash = e;
    document.cookie = "lastBrowseBookmark=" + window.location.pathname + "?" + e + ";path=/;";
    document.cookie = "lastViewedBeforeLogin=" + location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + "?" + e + ";path=/;";
    var h = $("#forwardURL");
    if (h) {
        var a = window.location.pathname + "?" + e;
        $("#forwardURL").attr("value", a);
        var c = $("#AccountLogin");
        if (c && c.length > 0) {
            $("#AccountLogin").removeAttr("href");
            $("#AccountLogin").attr("href", "/LogonForm?storeId=10054&catalogId=10001&forward=" + encodeURIComponent(a));
            $("#AccountLogin").removeAttr("data-navigate");
            $("#AccountLogin").attr("data-navigate", "/LogonForm?storeId=10054&catalogId=10001&forward=" + encodeURIComponent(a))
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        data: f,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(m) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            if (d && d == "Y") {
                $(window).scrollTop(0)
            }

            attachClickEvent();
            loadItemImages();
            loadSpanForSearchTab();
            scrollToFiter();              // here iam calling the function   
          try {

            }
          catch (err) {}
            return false;
        },
        error: function(j) {
            $("#loader").hide();
            alert("error~~~: " + j)
        }
    })
}
```

**Function :**

```
function scrollToFiter() {
 $('#search-refine-bar').on('click', function(e) {
    var eventNode = e.target.nodeName;
        $(e.target).attr({
            tabindex: "-1",
            focus: "focus"
        }).addClass('highlight').focus().css({
            "border": "1px solid #f00"
        });
 });
}
```

i know that click wont work when ajax call is done, iam looking for same other way, like instead of getting the "element" on click, do we have any event to capture the element.

Thanks !

Comment: show your ajax code, also a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: is your problem that, when you load content from ajax it will not fire click event any more? Or please clarify what you want to achieve from what you have, example: I want to capture click event, next send some data based on that element to the server, replace it with somehting, but to be able... blah

Comment: Why not create a global variable (var statement preceding all functions in the script block), and set its value to the "retrieved data" (in the function that does the data-retrieving)?  It should still be holding that data after the AJAX call.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili, No no.. assume iam adding a class onclick of the element before ajax call, once the ajax request is success, that class which i added is not present and getting removed., let me share you screenshot and js fiddle.

Comment: @syd that would be good ;))

Comment: @vernonner3voltazim, i could do that, but there will be multiple elements, like select box, checkbox and even p tags etc., so i cannot add statically, so iam trying to get the element on ajax call.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be global variables or the hidden input to the job instead.

```
var x = document.getElementById("myInput"); .
<input type="hidden" name="lan" id="myInput" value="some value">
```

You can do something like this
[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/6a6ftu2f/)